# How can I turn off the CakePHP Profiler for a specific page?

Tags: cakephp

I want to turn off the CakePHP profiler when working locally for a specific page that runs an ajax call.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple , in your action put 
`function action() {
 .... ;
 Configure::write('debug', '0');
 .... ;
}`

Answer (score 2):

User talelcool's solution is what you need.

However, if you have a lot of actions that deal with AJAX, you could do what I do and put it in the beforeFilter. You'll need the RequestHandler component though.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('RequestHandler');

    function beforeFilter() {

      if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {  
          Configure::write('debug',0);  
      }  

    }
}
```